# Converting decimal to Hexa - how do I make it shorter?

Tags: python, int, hex

I wrote a code that should convert integer to hexadecimals. This is a school Homework. I wrote quite a bit, afterwards a friend of mine showed me his code, which is a lot shorter, which is why I would like to know where I overcomplicated things, and where I can cut things away.
As a side note, I've been learning for 2 months now so please take easy on me :)!

Well I checked my code, but I couldn't find anything that I could delete or simplify.

```
       def Exponent2():                    # which exponent I need to 
                                                           devide with
       global Exponent
       Exponent = 0
       while True:
             a = dezimal // 16**Exponent
             Exponent = Exponent + 1
             if a == 0:
             Exponent = Exponent - 1
             break

        Exponent2()
        Ergebnis = ''
        Dezimal2 = dezimal
        while Dezimal2 != 0:
            dezimal = Dezimal2 // 16**Exponent
            Dezimal2 = Dezimal2 % 16**Exponent
            CheckReverse()
            Ergebnis = Ergebnis + str(dezimal)
            Exponent = Exponent - 1

        Länge = len(Ergebnis)
        Ergebnis = Ergebnis[1:Länge]
        print(Ergebnis)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you find the largest exponent `x` where you can divide the number by `16**x`. Instead, you can start with the smallest exponent that you can divide by. In other words, if you just divide by 16, then you get a single digit, then divide by 16 again to get the next hex digit.